# Including row in left join where data doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that shows me combined data between 2 tables

Currently the tables look like so:

```
person:ID,
Name,
Age


Form
ID,
Person_ID,
question,
answer


Example data would be
1 |Brandon| 55
2 |John |88
3 |Bob| 100


Form:
1 |1 |do you have diabetes |Y
2 |1 |do you take medications| Y
3 |1| how many times a week |7
4 |2|do you have diabetes |N
```

What I've tried is the following:

```
SELECT 
p.Name
er1.answer,
er2.answer,
er3.answer
from person p
LEFT JOIN form er1 ON p.ID = er1.Person_ID
LEFT JOIN form er2 ON p.ID = er2.Person_ID 
LEFT JOIN form er3 ON p.ID = er3.Person_ID
where er1.question='do you have diabetes'
and er2.question='do you take medications'
and er3.question='how many times a week'
```

The issue is that person 2 doesn't show up, because they answered No, the database didn't take in the other 2 questions. Is there a way to have the query search and pull the data and just have a null value there if it doesn't exist.

Comment: a predicate (condition) in the `WHERE` clause that requires a column to be non-NULL (e.g. `er2.var_name = 'x')  will negate the "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN`, Think of it this way: when a matching row isn't found, the database will create a dummy row to act as a matching row, and that dummy row consists of all NULL values. One option is to modify the conditions in the `WHERE` clause to allow NULL values e.g. , `WHERE (er1.question = 'x' OR er1.question IS NULL) AND ...` ,  or we could more the conditions out of the `WHERE` clause up to the `ON` clause of the outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Move the conditions in the `ON` clauses and remove the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  p.Name,
  er1.answer,
  er2.answer,
  er3.answer
from person p
LEFT JOIN form er1 ON p.ID = er1.Person_ID AND er1.question='do you have diabetes'
LEFT JOIN form er2 ON p.ID = er2.Person_ID AND er2.question='do you take medications'
LEFT JOIN form er3 ON p.ID = er3.Person_ID AND er3.question='how many times a week'
```

It would be better if you gave proper aliases to the columns:

```
SELECT 
  p.Name,
  er1.answer as `do you have diabetes`,
  er2.answer as `do you take medications`,
  er3.answer as `how many times a week`
from person p
LEFT JOIN form er1 ON p.ID = er1.Person_ID AND er1.question='do you have diabetes'
LEFT JOIN form er2 ON p.ID = er2.Person_ID AND er2.question='do you take medications'
LEFT JOIN form er3 ON p.ID = er3.Person_ID AND er3.question='how many times a week'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9BZTTdoycRXL4wASwak2Hm/1).
Results:

```
| Name    | do you have diabetes | do you take medications | how many times a week |
| ------- | -------------------- | ----------------------- | --------------------- |
| Brandon | Y                    | Y                       | 7                     |
| John    | N                    |                         |                       |
| Bob     |                      |                         |                       |
```

Now consider another way of getting the results you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  p.Name,
  max(case question when 'do you have diabetes' then answer end) as `do you have diabetes`,
  max(case question when 'do you take medications' then answer end) as `do you take medications`,
  max(case question when 'do you have diabetes' then answer end) as `how many times a week`
from person p LEFT JOIN form f ON p.ID = f.Person_ID 
group by p.ID, p.Name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9BZTTdoycRXL4wASwak2Hm/2).

Comment: Yes! and sorry, I was copying and pasting everywhere and it was meant to be question and not var_name, my apologizes on that one

Comment: @BrandonMacmillan if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.